# scripting a deletion of backed up files after backup is complete in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, archive

So my backup program will be backing up archive files. I want to then list them and remove them from the server. A log file gets created after a successful backup as 000000#.XLOG. I can grab the files from the log with the following:

cat 00000008.XLOG | grep string1 | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1 | grep string2 | grep .log

I can then remove those said files.

What I need help with is how to dynamically search the correct backups log file (the backup that just occurred) to be able to grab the files and delete them. Any suggestions are appreciated. I was thinking of somehow getting a time stamp at the beginning of the script then grabbing the info from any .xlog file newer than said timestamp because there should only be the one since the script makes the time stamp, kicks off the backup, and then grabs the files and deletes them. I just don't know the syntax for that.

Any help or further suggestions would be appreciated.

ls -l of the dir where the log files get stored:

> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   2154 Feb 29 23:46 00000001.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  10153 Feb 29 23:46 00000001.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1308 Mar  6 03:22 00000002.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   5257 Mar  6 03:22 00000002.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1276 Mar  6 03:23 00000003.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   4565 Mar  6 03:23 00000003.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1280 Mar  6 03:26 00000004.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   4662 Mar  6 03:26 00000004.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1278 Mar  6 03:27 00000005.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   4748 Mar  6 03:27 00000005.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1278 Mar  6 03:29 00000006.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   4838 Mar  6 03:29 00000006.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1280 Mar  6 03:30 00000007.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   5881 Mar  6 03:30 00000007.DTA
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1240 Mar  6 03:30 00000007.DTX
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   4929 Mar  6 03:30 00000007.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  14019 Mar 31 04:43 00000008.CAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 220750 Mar 31 04:43 00000008.DTA
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  12160 Mar 31 04:43 00000008.DTX
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  97720 Mar 31 04:43 00000008.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    768 Mar 31 04:43 BackupStatus.xml
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    768 Mar 31 21:22 RestoreStatus.xml
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   5360 Mar 31 21:22 RST20160331-212219.XLOG
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1533 Mar 31 21:22 SYNCH.DAT
>
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1533 Mar 31 21:22 SYNCH.MIR

output of my command:

> /dir/dir/dir/arch.log
>
> /dir/dir/dir/arch2.log
>
> /dir/dir/dir/arch3.log

and so on

This is the general layout of the file:

```
<M ID="4384" O="VV" C="BKUP" S="I" T="2016-03-08T09:43:52. 0-08:00"></M>

<M ID="4314" C="BKUP" S="I" T="2016-03-08T09:43:52. 0-08:00"><PS><P T="0">7.20.5420 Oct 21 2013 12:01:35</P></PS></M>

<M ID="4127" C="BKUP" S="I" T="2016-03-08T09:43:52. 0-08:00"><PS><P T="1">2016-03-08T09:43:52. 0-08:00</P></PS></M>
```

Comment: please show the result of 'ls -l' in the involved directory, plus output of your one-liner command, and finaly a significant abstract of the file which would contain timestamps.

Comment: So ... are you saying that what you're really after is to delete the source of backups that have just successfully completed? Is it possible that this is an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), and that what you really want to use is `rsync --remove-source-files` ?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. The only issue is that I have to use my backup program as a company requirement and for retention/compression/encryption purposes. The only way I can get the "source files" is to get them from the current 00000#.XLOG as that is the only thing that lists them. This changes with every backup and is written after a backup is complete.

Answer (score 0):

> A log file gets created after a successful backup as 000000#.XLOG

and

> What I need help with is how to dynamically search the correct backups log file (the backup that just occurred) to be able to grab the files and delete them.

All together I understand that the very last **.XLOG** file created is the one associated to the last successful backup.

To list the very last **.XLOG** file created:

```
ls -1rt *.XLOG | tail -n 1
```

With your one-liner command:

```
grep string1 $(ls -1rt *.XLOG | tail -n 1) | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1 | grep string2 | grep .log
```

### ----

There is below a **safe** version, if there are special chars in the filename:

```
find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0"  | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\000";} {if (!newesttimestamp || ($1 > newesttimestamp)) {newesttimestamp=$1;newestline=$0;}} END{if (newestline) {print substr(newestline,23);}}'
```

With your one-liner command:

```
grep string1 $(find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0"  | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\000";} {if (!newesttimestamp || ($1 > newesttimestamp)) {newesttimestamp=$1;newestline=$0;}} END{if (newestline) {print substr(newestline,23);}}') | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1 | grep string2 | grep .log
```

### ----

Commands already provided had been tested with examples, except the updated one-liners.

*The commands below have not been tested.*

Test the one-liner command with a final **while** block:

```
$ grep string1 $(find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0"  | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\000";} {if (!newesttimestamp || ($1 > newesttimestamp)) {newesttimestamp=$1;newestline=$0;}} END{if (newestline) {print substr(newestline,23);}}') | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1 | grep string2 | grep .log | while read -r line; do printf "%s\n" "${line}"; done
```

When everything is ok, replace the **printf** in the last **while** block with **rm**:

```
$ grep string1 $(find . -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0"  | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\000";} {if (!newesttimestamp || ($1 > newesttimestamp)) {newesttimestamp=$1;newestline=$0;}} END{if (newestline) {print substr(newestline,23);}}') | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d '>' -f2 | cut -d '<' -f1 | grep string2 | grep .log | while read -r line; do rm -- "${line}"; done
```

Comment: hmmmm, I'll have to try this out. The only possible issue I can see is that the 00000#.XLOG files aren't the only .XLOG files in the dir. There are .XLOG files for restores and synchs.

Comment: also, if i pipe that to a .lst how can i go through that list file and remove the separate files that are in the list? They will have their full paths.

Comment: @invaderzimpoo the answer had been updated, look atthe bottom.

Comment: I'm so daft. How does that integrate with my one liner?

Comment: @invaderzimpoo you could use the one-liner with a final `> filesToDelete.lst`, The bottom part had been updated with another solution.